# Group $G$ such that $(ab)^p = a^pb^p$ for some prime $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

This is a question taken from Herstein's "Topics in Algebra", second edition, section 2.6. It goes:

> Let $G$ be a group such that $(ab)^p = a^p b^p$ for all $a, b \in G$, where $p$ is a prime number. Let $S = \{ x \in G \mid x^{p^m} = e\text{ for some } m \text{ depending on }x\}$. Prove:
>
> (a) $S$ is normal in $G$;
>
> (b) If $\overline{G} = G/S$ and if $\overline{x} \in \overline{G}$ is such that $\overline{x}^p = \overline{e}$ then $\overline{x} = \overline{e}$

### My solution

(a)

- $S$ is closed: if $x, y \in S$, there are some $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^{p^m} = y^{p^n} = e$. Therefore, if we take $m+n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(xy)^{p^{m+n}} = x^{p^{m+n}} y^{p^{m+n}}$ (this can be proved by induction) $= (x^{p^{m}})^{p^n}(y^{p^n})^{p^m} = e$
- $e \in S$, trivially
- If $x \in S$, you can take the same $m \in \mathbb{N}$ for $x^{-1}$
- If $x \in S$ and $g \in G$, $(gxg^{-1})^{p^m} = gx^{p^m}g^{-1} = e$, so $S$ is normal in $G$

(b)

If $\overline{x}^p = \overline{e}$, then $x^p \in S$, which means there is some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(x^p)^{p^m} = e$, meaning $x^{p^{m+1}} = e$, and so $x \in S \iff \overline{x} = \overline{e}$

### The induction proof

For $m = 1$, the claim is clear by hypothesis. If $(xy)^{p^k} = x^{p^k}y^{p^k}$ for all $k$ up to $m \in \mathbb{N}$, then $(xy)^{p^m} = (xy)^{p^{m-1}*p} = ((xy)^{p^{m-1}})^p = (x^{p^{m-1}}y^{p^{m-1}})^p = x^{p^m}y^{p^m}$, which concludes the proof.

### The question

My problem is that never have I used the primality of p, and I sort of assumed $m \in \mathbb{N}$, as Herstein gives no indication of where $m$ is taken from in the set definition.

Is the above proof correct? As I said, I suspect not, because of the extra condition on $p$, but I can't see a mistake here, and I have been looking for a while now... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's correct. For this exercise $p$ could be any positive integer.

Comment: Can you please give me the reason behind "If $\overline{x}^p = \overline{e}$, then $x^p\in S$"? Maybe, I'm missing something trivial, but I really don't seem to get why that's true.

Comment: @SayanDutta It's true by definition of quotient groups

Comment: @Gauss I'm still not getting it. How are $\overline{x}$ and $x$ related by the way? I understand, $\overline{e}$ to be the identity of $\overline{G}$. Am I right? Can you please be a little more elaborate...

Comment: @SayanDutta $\overline{x} = xS$ for any $x$ in $G/S$. Thus $\overline{x^p} = \overline{e} \iff x^pS = S$. In particular, since $S \leq G$, $e \in S$, which means, by the coset equality, $x^p e \in S \iff x^p \in S$

Comment: @Gauss got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note: technically, $X = \{\overline{x} \mid x \in G\}$ is a subset of $G$. $X$ is what’s called a **transversal** of $S$ in $G$. It contains one, and exactly one, representative from each coset of $G/S$. However, in the case that $S$ is normal in $G$, if you define the mapping $f: X \to G/S$ by $\overline{x} \mapsto xS$, you get an isomorphism, hence why we can treat things the way I did above.

Comment: @SayanDutta You’re welcome! Happy to help!